# Error while using webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

So I want to use a webbrowser to show an html file, and print it. I can load the file, but when I try to use `webBrowser1.ShowPrintDialog();` I have a script error. I tried to disable this with `webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;` but it doesn't work.
The weird part is that when I run my code in debug(F5), it works, but not in "normal" mode (Ctrl + F5).

My code so far is very simple:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    webBrowser1.ShowPrintDialog();
}
```

Comment: Could you show the error you are receiving?

Comment: http://imgur.com/HUno4a1 It's in french :/ But it says : Script error, an error occurred in the script of this page. At line 1791.

Comment: I'm unsure if this will help you but i ran this code in a new Solution perfectly. Are you using `"http://google.com"` to test with?

Comment: Yeah, I think my IDE is a bit bugged, I use Visual studio 2012 (with a legal key), I'm downloading visual studio 2010 C# express, I'll test.